# How to change the button color when it is active CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

This is my code is OK

```
#wpbody-content a {
    width 100%;
    background: #363636;
    color: #fff;
}
```

my code hover is OK

```
#wpbody-content a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

this is not working?

```
#wpbody-content a:active
    background: #fff;
            color: #000;
```

Comment: `#wpbody-content a:active { .. }`

Comment: i have try that but is not working!

Comment: you're gonna have to add the whole `not working` code and the desired result

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Comment: You need to define "Not working". The problem here is either *you made a typo and it doesn't work because of the syntax error that a CSS validator would find* or *you think :active means "a link to the page currently being viewed"* (it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

It Will work But you need to change color or background or the booth of active code like this:

```
<style>
    #wpbody-content a {
        width: 100%;
        background: #363636;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #wpbody-content a:hover {
        background: #fff;
        color: #000;
    }
    #wpbody-content a:active{
        background: #003bb3 !important;
        color: #fff !important;
    }
</style>

<div id="wpbody-content">
    <a>Hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: i have this but is not working :active i do not understand whats the problem.

Comment: did you try to copy-paste my code in empty html page and open the page on same browser? i think you have other css on your code!

Comment: no this code is working perfect, but is not working in my webisite. maybe wordpress have some other code do not allow this code.

Comment: ok im added some code to my code, please insert it after all css code  of files on your page ...

Comment: thanks for your help, maybe i have some other probelm for that is not working, i have try and before with !important; but do not work.